# Is there a way for the server owners instead of the bot creator of discord.py to choose what role the bot will auto assign to new members that join?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, roles, auto

## Something similar to this but allows any server owner to decide what role is auto assigned instead of whoever made the bot.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
     default_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=DEFAULT_ROLE_ID)
     await member.add_roles(default_role)
```

Comment: I would recommend using a database to store the default role ID. Then you can access it each time a member joins. You can also create a config command for owners to use that can change the database defaultrole slot.

Answer (score -1):

```
DEFAULT_ROLE_IDs = []
@client.event 
    async def on_member_join(member):
            default_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=DEFAULT_ROLE_ID) 
            await member.add_roles(default_role)

@client.command()
@client.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def default(ctx, roleID: int):
     found = False
     stored_i = None
     for i in DEFAULT_ROLE_IDs:
           if i[0] == ctx.guild.id:
                 i[1] = roleID
                 break
     if not found: 
          DEFAULT_ROLE_IDs.append([ctx.guild.id, roleID])
```

From what I understood from your question, the best way would simply be to make a new command that allows any server administrator to set the default role.

You could try adding a command like the one above, which allows admins to set the default role through a command in discord. This relies on the use of the `DEFAULT_ROLE_ID` variable. Feel free to use databases if you want to store the IDs elsewhere.

Comment: Would this work if I made more then one server? Like if I were too create one server and set the role id for that one then made another then set another role id for the second server would both servers get set with the same role id? Or would it work properly for both?

Comment: For that, you are better off using a database to store the data. However, assuming you don't have any knowledge with DBs / SQL, you can check my edited answer so that you can have separate role IDs for different servers